# Delay in CSS Appearing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm **very** new to coding and have been just trying to code in my spare time. I have a code that when I go to view it has an obvious delay in the CSS. When you first load it for about a second the background will show as solid pink, the font changes, and the social media icons do not appear at the bottom of the screen. I have tried to search through here for answers, but the situations I've found that are similar to mine I didn't quite understand the answers as I have only been coding for about 3 weeks now.

Below is my HTML code and my CSS code:

```css
/* BODY */

body {
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/vPn6tqR/clouds.jpg');
  }
  
.cover-body {
    background-color: #ffd5cd;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    color: #8675a9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.cover-btn {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #8675a9;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    border-width: medium;
}

.cover-btn:hover {
    color: #2e2933;
}

.cover-header {
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.cover-p {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.pc-cover-logo {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 7rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 63%;
    bottom:84%;
}



/* FOOTER */

a {
    color: #8675a9;
}

a:hover {
    color: #c3aed6;
}

.footer {
    font-size: 80%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-media-icons {
    word-spacing: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <!-- HEAD -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Palette Clouds</title>

        <!-- Google Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

        <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8346f7b19f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>


    <!-- BODY -->
 
    <body class="cover-body">

        <img alt="photo of clouds" class="pc-cover-logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/KrXCrp2/PC-Logo.png">
        <p class="cover-p">welcome to</p>
        <h1 class="cover-header">Palette Clouds</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light cover-btn">coming soon</button>

    
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="social-media-icons">
                <a class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" href="https://twitter.com/paletteclouds" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x" href="https://www.facebook.com/PaletteClouds/" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" href="https://www.instagram.com/paletteclouds/" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" href="mailto:dionna@paletteclouds.com"></a>
            </div>
            <p>© 2020 Palette Clouds</p>
        </footer>

    </body>

</html>
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!!

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Icon are here and everything seems to apear as it should

Comment: well I think his issue is the short delay until it is displayed. However this is simply because of load of external resources. As he uses an external css not hosted on his server directly, it has to be addintionally loaded from another site first which will cause a delay.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help. I was so frustrated because I thought it was something wrong with my code. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an inline style like this:

```
<body class="cover-body" style="background-color: #ffd5cd;">
```

It makes it just that little bit faster and seems to prevent the flicker.

Update your css too:

```
.cover-body {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    color: #8675a9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e23udzk8/

Answer (score -2):

How pages normally load is as follow:

- HTML render first then css is called.
  So here your image is called later (the few secs delay that you wait between html render and css), so a hack I use would be having a hidden image tag with the background source so the image source used in the background image will be loaded in the html render therefore faster and causing no delay until css load.

Also please notice that one reason of the delay is the huge size of the image so reducing the image size will decrease the loading time as well.

```css
body {
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/vPn6tqR/clouds.jpg');
  }
  
.cover-body {
    background-color: #ffd5cd;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    color: #8675a9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.cover-btn {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #8675a9;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    border-width: medium;
}

.cover-btn:hover {
    color: #2e2933;
}

.cover-header {
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.cover-p {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.pc-cover-logo {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 7rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 63%;
    bottom:84%;
}

img {
  display: none; //Added Code
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <!-- HEAD -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Palette Clouds</title>

        <!-- Google Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&family=Libre+Baskerville&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

        <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8346f7b19f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>


    <!-- BODY -->
 
    <body class="cover-body">

        <img alt="photo of clouds" class="pc-cover-logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/KrXCrp2/PC-Logo.png">
        <p class="cover-p">welcome to</p>
        <h1 class="cover-header">Palette Clouds</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light cover-btn">coming soon</button>

    
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="social-media-icons">
                <a class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" href="https://twitter.com/paletteclouds" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x" href="https://www.facebook.com/PaletteClouds/" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" href="https://www.instagram.com/paletteclouds/" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" href="mailto:dionna@paletteclouds.com"></a>
            </div>
            <p>© 2020 Palette Clouds</p>
        </footer>


<img src='https://i.ibb.co/vPn6tqR/clouds.jpg'/> //Added Code
    </body>

</html>
```